# In constant contact I have to add contact one more list

Tags: c#, constantcontact

I have a contact in a particular list that I also wants to add to another list.
Below code was working but suddely its stops working dont know why?

Neither I am getting any error. Is I am doing anything wrong here.

```
string[] emailAddress = new string[] { list[i].EmailAddress };
IList<Contact> myList = Utility.SearchContactByEmail(authenticationData, emailAddress, out nextChunkId);
Contact thisContact =  Utility.GetContactDetailsById(authenticationData, myList[0].Id);

thisContact.Id = myList[0].Id;

ContactOptInList newList = new ContactOptInList();
newList.OptInSource = ContactOptSource.ActionByCustomer;
newList.ContactList = new ContactList("3");
//Contact list you want to add them to
thisContact.ContactLists.Add(newList);
```

Comment: What does "stops working" mean? Expected/actual results?

Comment: It Is not throwing any exception neither it is updating the list.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling something like: `Utility.UpdateContactSmallForm(AuthenticationData, thisContact)`?

Comment: thanks for your reply Alex, I cant't see method  UpdateContactSmallForm() but there is UpdateContactFullForm() by using it I am geting error The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: I found the reason behind this actually list order in constact is not matching with id of list if one of the list is deleted.thats why when I was giving id 3 it actulay updating list having id 5 as 2 list in between are deleted. and if tyr 2 i got bad request error as list with that id has been deleted thats why I got confused hope this will help some one ..